# Integral of square root.

Tags: calculus, integration

We have
$$\int \sqrt{x} \text{  }dx=\int x^{1/2} \text{  }dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}+C.$$
But, let $u=\sqrt{x}$. Then $x=u^2$, and $dx=2udu$. Substituting, we have
$$\int \sqrt{x} \text{  }dx=\int 2u^2 \text{  }du=\frac{2}{3}x^3+C.$$

Which one is correct, and why?

Comment: Did you remember to reverse-substitute $u=\sqrt x$ instead of $u=x$?

Comment: substituting $u=x$ would give $\int 2u \sqrt{u} du$, so yes..

Comment: He means after the integration. You should have $2u^3/3+C $ where $u=\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \sqrt{x} \text{  }dx=\int 2u^2 \text{  }du=\frac{2}{3}u^3+C.$$

Remember, after substituting, we need to calculate the integral with respect to $u$.

Once that's done, *then* "back"-substitute $\sqrt x = u$ to get $$\frac 23(x^{1/2})^3 + C = \frac 23 x^{3/2} + C$$

Comment: I had a definite integral to calculate, so resubstitution didn't matter. it's late so I missed it! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have $u= \sqrt{x}$, hence $\int 2u^2 du = \frac{2u^3}{3}+C= \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}+C$

Comment: ok. I feel stupid now...

Comment: Don't, I think I've made the exact same mistake before.